# Remove indentation in section after using labels

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I want to remove the indentation that occurs after I use a label at a section. How can I remove this?

So how do I remove the indentation (the space) at `text2` that is created at my pdf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{test1}
Text1
\section{test2}~\label{test2}
Text2
\end{document}
```

I have this also with chapters and subsections.

Comment: Use `\section{test2}\label{test2}` instead of `\section{test2}~\label{test2}` or in other words: remove the `~`.

Comment: `\label` makes no visible output so the `~` before it is completely wrong, it should be after, or better, in the argument of `\section`.  So `\section{test2\label{test2}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `~` between `\section` and `\label` the undesired indentation is removed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{test1}
Text1
\section{test2}\label{test2}
Text2
\end{document}
```

---

With `\ref`:

[image: see]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{test1}
Text1
\section{test2}\label{test2}
Text2 Reference to the second section's label: \ref{test2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But then the labels are not working correct or am I saying something wrong?

Comment: @jenniferruurs: Did you test that? Please see my updated answer fo another example including a `\ref` to section 2. As you can see from the screenshot, the `\ref` command returns the expected number. If this does not work for you, please add a MWE showing how you used `\ref`. If this does not answer your question, please clarify, what you refer to with " the labels are not working correct ".

Comment: you are right, thank you (a fellow worker told me to place the `~`)